# Image viewer for Windows with logging of displayed files

Tags: windows, images, logs, image-viewer

I'm looking for image viewer for Windows with logging option (to logfile or trace) of currently displayed files (image path + date/time).

(the browser should allow you to view the other images in the same folder).

Optional ability to log other events (eg switching to / from the browser window).

Do you know any? (I was looking for - but have not found).

Comment: What does that *(the browser* sentence have to do with your software request?

Comment: What limits "other events"? There are hundreds of events on a PC per second (see [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) for a proof). What is important to be logged and what not? Why is switching the browser (which I guess to be the image viewer) relevant?

Answer (score -1):

Google Chrome has a lesser known inbuilt file browser, just type file:/// in the address bar and enter any directory with images then open images in a new tab

EDIT:

Okay so here's how to do this. Create a folder anywhere say in the C:\ Drive and fill it with pictures.

1.) For eg: C:\hello\

2.) Open Google chrome

3.) type file:/// in your web address area

4.) Navigate to C:\ drive

5.) Navigate to the folder

6.) All the images are time stamped and have their paths logged with other infromation and can be opened like HTML links in a new tab.

You can also use it directly as file:/// +++ PATH TO FOLDER HERE +++

Enjoy!

Comment: How does it log the time and the file name?

Comment: Yes. Try it out yourself. Look at my EDIT

Comment: Your description fails in Google Chrome 52.0.2743.116 (up-to-date at the time of writing; Windows) in step 3 already. It does not display a file open dialog. I was able to fix that by typing file:///c:\hello. But it is technically wrong when you say: "all images are time stamped". This is the NTFS MAC time stamp, which has nothing to do when you last viewed the image. Just try the following: look at a picture today and tomorrow. It won't tell you that you have seen this picture today and tomorrow.

Comment: Well I guess then there must be some modifications necessary to make the above steps work..? All in all thats the basic idea I guess, open chrome, get shortcut do stuff. Changes might be there in some places.

Also I dont get it, you view the image today and tomorrow? You travel in time to view it tomorrow, travel back to the past, open up your browser and  then expect something, that hasnt even occurred, to show?

Comment: How I view the image today and tomorrow? Because I can't tell you to view it today and yesterday if you haven't looked at it yesterday already. But it's possible to wait until tomorrow, isn't it?

Comment: But it is technically wrong when you say that "look at a picture today and tomorrow ". I guess you should have to mention it explicitly that you're viewing it on the third day after waiting two days, how else would people know?. I guess your explanation fails in your latest argument itself